# Elmah works on localhost, but not on production?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, elmah, production-environment, elmah.mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC 3 app, I've configured Elmah, and then Elmah.MVC for error logging. Both of which log just fine when running on localhost (Windows 7, IIS 6.1). On a production server (2008 R2, IIS 6.1), no errors are logged. I can browse to the /elmah directory in the site without problem (I've allowed remote access for now.) I've set the proper permissions to a folder for XML logging but nothing logged. I back-tracked to use the "in memory" logger, still no log. I've made sure modules and handlers were referenced correctly in both system.web and system.webserver.

I've browsed a lot of posts related to Elmah config issues, permissions, etc., but have not yet found the cause of this.

Are there other security/permissions issues that I'm missing on the production server related to Elmah? What else could be causing this?

Comment: is that still actual? i could assume, something wrong with configuration of your production machine. maybe some iis extensions are set that catch all errors, so elmah could not catch anything..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do NOT have "Read Only" checked on the folder. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still current but I was having a similar issue: it all worked perfectly on my local computer *and* on the web server when you had customErrors mode="Off" but if you changed customErrors to RemoteOnly then it would only work if you accessed the website locally. 
The solution was to add a new Elmah filter on the FilterConfig section that guarantees elmah will always log the errors regardless of the customErrors mode. Here is the post with details: http://forums.asp.net/t/1687875.aspx?Elmah+Error+Log+is+not+working+my+production+Server

Here is the code snippet (credit to the person on the post):

```
public class FilterConfig {
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters) {
        filters.Add(new ElmahHandledErrorLoggerFilter());
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}

public class ElmahHandledErrorLoggerFilter : IExceptionFilter {
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context) {
        //if (context.ExceptionHandled) // Log only handled exceptions, because all other will be caught by ELMAH anyway.
        //We want elmah to log ALL exceptions
        ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(context.Exception);
    }
}
```